# MongoDB save() Successful but not showing on MongoDB dashboard

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I have a very weird problem. Inserting documents using mongoose and mongodb was working perfectly, but all of the sudden, it's not working. I've verified that save() is successful (taking into account that it's async, of course) and also received a response with the new document data on Postman, but it's not showing up on the dashboard.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've tested with other POST routes, but all the ones that used to work no longer work. Are the new documents really being created? What am I missing?

Comment: Have you ever seen the data on the dashboard when using `mongoose`?

Comment: Yes, I've been able to successfully see data on the dashboard previously.